# Applying last-child to element not working

Tags: css, css-selectors

Given I have the following tags:

```html
<div id="div-one">
    <div class="div-two">some </div>
    <input type="hidden" value=""/>
    <div class="div-two">some </div>
    <input type="hidden" value=""/>
    <div class="div-two">some </div>
    <input type="hidden" value=""/>
</div>
```

When I try to apply a style to the **last** "div-two" element using this css syntax:

```
#div-one div.div-two:last-child  { border-bottom:solid 1px #999; }
```

It doesn't work unless I remove the hidden fields. Any suggestions as to why?

- Here's a link to the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/67qYJ/1/
- Using Google Chrome v12.0.742.100
- It is **NOT** an option to place the hidden tags elsewhere

Comment: May I ask which browser(s) you tested this in?

Comment: What browser and version are you testing in? `:last-child` has less support than `:first-child`, I believe it is a CSS3 selector.

Comment: I do believe Chrome supports `:last-child`, and has done so since ever - can you put up a test page so we can check it out?

Comment: @Coderama: Can you create an example on http://jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: This works fine in my Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/8D9UH/

Comment: @Coderama: Ask Chrome's developer tools about the computed styles. Something else might be interfering with your given CSS.

Comment: Now that's a very very different structure to what you originally provided. A lesson learned...

Comment: Changing last-child to first-child does work, so it is probably a Chrome bug

Comment: @jao: No, it's a misunderstanding of `:last-child` (and `:first-child`).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your selector doesn't work for your current markup because the last child is an `input`, *not* a `div.div-two`.

Is `div#div-one` only going to contain those two kinds of elements? If so, you can use `:last-of-type` instead, which picks the last `div` (though regardless of its class):

```
#div-one div:last-of-type { border-bottom:solid 1px #999; }
```

However if your inner `div` elements have other classes besides `.div-two`, it will be pretty difficult to choose the last `.div-two` element. Your given code makes it easy because `div` and `input` are distinct element types and only the `.div-two` class is present.

Comment: You nailed it! Thanks! So i ended up using the :last-of-type but for the class selector which seems to work.

Comment: @Coderama: Be careful, as the `:nth-of-type` family only looks at an element's type (the name you see in its HTML tags). Adding class selectors just narrows down the selection. If you don't add a type selector like `div`, it will pick any element that's the last one of its type.

Answer (score 2):

If you can't use `last-of-type` like @BoltClock suggested you could just add a second class to the last `.div-two` in the group.

http://jsfiddle.net/watss/

```
<div class="div-two last">some </div>
```

and

```
#div-one > .div-two.last { border-bottom:1px solid; background:yellow; }
```

or better yet

```
#div-one > .last { border-bottom:1px solid; background:yellow; }
```